# How to access the background thread in Robolectric?

Tags: multithreading, robolectric

I'm testing a code in a Robolectric runner. The code under test verifies it's not executed on the main thread:

```
    if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == java.lang.Thread.currentThread()) {
        new IllegalStateException("Method called on the UI thread");
    }
```

The Robolectric test raises this exception, and I don't want that.
I tried running the code from a `Robolectric.getBackgroundScheduler()` but I sill have the exception.

How can my test start run in a different thread?

Comment: Make a utility method or class and mock it. That is unfortunate and not nice solution

Comment: Which robolectric do you use?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the check can use a utility method:

```
static void checkMainThread() {
  if (isRunningInRobolectric()) {
    return;
  }
  if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == java.lang.Thread.currentThread()) {
    new IllegalStateException("Method called on the UI thread");
  }
}

static boolean isRunningInRobolectric() {
  return "robolectric".equals(Build.FINGERPRINT);
}
```